# How docker mounts volumes without making entry to /etc/mtab?

Tags: mount, docker

I am quite new to docker so spare me for stupid doubts. I've know that `/etc/mtab` reflects currently mounted partitions. I also see the following output in my `df -h` command:

```
# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            5.9G   12K  5.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1.2G  1.6M  1.2G   1% /run
/dev/sda4       220G  150G   59G  73% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            5.9G   70M  5.8G   2% /run/shm
none            100M   76K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda1       496M   18M  479M   4% /boot/efi
/dev/dm-1       9.8G  129M  9.1G   2% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/c737743ce2dc4ef68598eca9de89f37d17bfeeb435e6934b6d41216967093e26
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/396fd80e6258952508d2d5c10f2322af51445ca4c516245117e32a6a62c23e81/shm
```

The question is, that if `/dev/dm-1` is visible as a mounted partition in `df -h` then why it is not listed in /etc/mtab file ?

I use devicemapper storage driver for device. Also, is it possible to list my docker partition in /etc/mtab ? I am into some experimentation for which I need a docker volume entry in /etc/mtab.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You might be experiencing https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/linux.debian.bugs.dist/QxmQtwfYpr8

Answer (score 0):

Docker does so by just mounting w/o changing that file.

For detailed information just enter `man mount` and locate the section about the file. The manpage gives the hint that `/etc/mtab` is not well w/ containers:

> The programs **mount** and **umount** traditionally maintained a list of currently mounted filesystems in the file `/etc/mtab`. This real mtab file is still supported, but on current Linux systems it is better to make it a symlink to `/proc/mounts` instead, because a regular mtab file maintained in userspace cannot reliably work with namespaces, containers and other advanced Linux features.

So probably you find what you're looking for in `/proc/mounts`. Additionally the docker cli itself offers a lot of introspection features.